# How to configure a WCF Service Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, wcf-client

How can I create a WCF service (hosted in localhost) and then use a html page that consumes the localhost WCF service using jquery/js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look here...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sridhar_subra/116/

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wcf/article.php/c18171/JQuery-and-WCF-Working-Hand-in-hand.htm

Comment: Do I need to host the page in localhost for this to work? (like it's in the first link that you gave). Or can I have a simple html page (with jquery code) in my C:\ directory and when I put in firefox it works?

Comment: You need to host the page, you can call your service using AJAX only if the client page is on the same host and is called with the same protocol (Same Origin Policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: And how can I access to it without hosting in the page?